# fabric process getting break after kill linux command execution

Tags: python, fabric

I've set of run() statements in my fabric file to stop/exit my app servers. When i run fab file, fabric process getting break after the following statement. Can someone tell me how to resolve it?

```
run("kill $(ps x | grep memcached | awk '{print $1}')", pty=False)
```

Comment: How is fabric exiting? With error messages? Is yes, which one?

Comment: Im getting "Terminated" if i use above one.
I'm getting "Killed" if i use run("kill -9 `ps x | grep memcached | awk '{print $1}'`", pty=False)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use pkill instead and call it a day